# xbox360 gamepad left analog only moves up/down on fps games

Tags: games, gamepad, joystick

When I play fps games on ubuntu, my razer onza xbox360 gamepad controller works as it should except for when I use the left analog stick which only works up/down but it doesn't work left/right.  I have the jstest-gtk joysticks installed.
If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `jstest-gtk`, wiggle the sticks around and ensure that they all report to the computer properly (ignore the configuration in jstest-gtk, no modern game uses that)
2. Run Steam in Big Picture and configure your controller there, that should fix SDL2 based games, non-Steam games launched through Steam should work as well

For games outside of Steam you have to twiddle with the SDL_GAMECONTROLLERCONFIG variable, but I don't think there is a good tool for that yet, Steam handles that internally.

Also look around the game if you can configure anything in the game themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Unfortunately I tried what you suggested and I'm still having the same problem.  I ran jstest-gtk and all sticks and buttons seem to be doing fine.  I also ran Steam in Big Picture mode and everything there seems fine.  In fact, everything is fine with most games except for FPS games where my left stick only works with one axis.

Comment: Are you launching the game through Steam? If you do that and the controls still don't work, then the game is at fault and you either have to configure that in the game manually or send a bug report to the game developer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I'll have to send a bug report to the game developer then.